# Exception : Maximum request length exceeded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am getting the error Maximum request length exceeded when I am trying to upload a file more than 4 MB in MVC website.

I increased maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength ,but get same error

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />

<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" executionTimeout="600"/>
```

Comment: I think this has been solved before: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

Comment: I tried this solution but same error

Answer (score 0):

try this, it is workin my projects

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1544096" requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="55590" />

<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000" />
```

Comment: it started to show progress bar but error happened again